# What is Add|Run Recipe command for?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

After installing ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta into Visual Studio 2010, I have this command in context menu after right-clicking on **Controllers** folder, but when I click it, there shows up **Select a recipe to run** dialog without anything to select. What is this thing for and why is such important to show up in context menu usually used to add controller (it's next to **Add|Controller** command)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's covered in the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253812):

> The new Recipes feature enables Visual Studio to generate
>   solution-specific code based on packages that you can install using
>   NuGet. The Recipes framework makes it easy for developers to write
>   code-generation plugins, which you can also use to replace the
>   built-in code generators for Add Area, Add Controller, and Add View.
>   Because recipes are deployed as NuGet packages, they can easily be
>   checked into source control and shared with all developers on the
>   project automatically. They are also available on a per-solution
>   basis.

The Haacked also [bloged](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/09/21/writing-a-recipe-for-asp-net-mvc-4-developer-preview.aspx) about recipes.

Comment: It's also important to note that right now they are in MVC4 but they will moved out of the project. Main reason is that it is more of a Nuget feature than an MVC one. More details can be read in the roadmap below (search for Recipe)

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap

Answer (score 0):

This may be phased out now, so please use with a caution. Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff697216.aspx

Comment: That link refers to GAT in Visual Studio 2010.  Thus I don't think its 'retired' status pertains to MVC4 recipes.